# How to vertically stack trained models in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have two trained models in keras that i want to stack one on the top of another to form one single model. I want to do this to combine my trained models into one.

[image]

I think merge(Merge) is for stacking models horizontally whereas I want to stack keras functional API models vertically.

PS : Output 1's shape is identical to Input 2

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/neural-networks-ensemble-33f33bea7df3

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
inputA = Input(input_shape_for_A)
outputA = modelA(inputA)
outputB = modelB(outputA)

modelC = Model(inputA, outputB)
```

Comment: do i have to connect the models in any way ??

Comment: The code in the answer is exactly how one connects models.

Comment: You can use any of the three models (A, B and C) as if they were loose, but their weights are shared.

Comment: thanks man, it works. can i ask you one more question ?  

how can i print the whole model summary of modelC ?

I tried modelC.summary() , but that game me the name of models constituting the modelC (like modelA and modelB). How can i get the layer names and their connections ??

Comment: I think you will need `modelA.summary()` and `modelB.summary()`. I don't know another way.

Comment: hey how can i define "inputA" for a model with multiple inputs ??

Comment: Define multiple inputs with `inputA = Input(shapeA)`, `inputB = Input(shapeB)`....

Answer (score 2):

The above method works fine. But when try `modelC.summary()` it will print only modelA, modelB names. Because you are creating a model in which it has models. Means modelC has modelA and modelB, not the layers. But modelA and modelB, have layers, so you can access `modelA.summary()`, `modelB.summary()`. You don't need what happens in modelC. Cause it just holds modelA and modelB together, like a single model.
To get `modelC.summary()`, you have to just follow this:

```
modelC = Sequential()

#since modelA input shape is also input shape for modelC
modelC.add(modelA.input)

# this adds all layers to modelC from modelA
for layer in modelA.layers:
    modelC.add(layer)

# since modelA output is input to modelB, you don't want any Input here, just add layers stacked to previous layers in modelC from modelB
for layer in modelB.layers:
    modelC.add(layer)
```

To check overall modelC, see `modelC.input`, this must match `modelA.input` and `modelC.output`, this must match `modelB.output`. To check whole model, `modelC.summary()`, and also verify whether all layers from modelA, and modelB are in modelC. If any quires, please feel free to ask. The above is useful you don't need this much of work but since you asked for layer names and connection, I replied this to you.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the accepted answer, this method works without having to redefine an input layer.

```py
modelC=Model(
    inputs=modelA.inputs,
    outputs=modelB(modelA(modelA.inputs))
)
```

In my use case, I have a pre-processor with multiple outputs and the main model has multiple inputs. The output layers for modelA have the same names as the input layers for modelB, but they may be defined in a different order. This function reorders the outputs of modelA appropriately and passes them to modelB.

```py
def stack_models(model1, model2):
    #get model output and input names
    model1_out_names=model1.output_names
    model2_in_names=model2.input_names
    
    #generate a sorted index that maps the order of model1 outputs to model2 inputs
    name_idx=[model1_out_names.index(name) for name in model2_in_names]
    
    model1_output=model1(model1.inputs)
    model2_input=[model1_output[idx] for idx in name_idx]
    model2_output=model2(model2_input)
    
    return tf.keras.Model(
        inputs=model1.inputs,
        outputs=model2_output
    )
```