# How do I train a chain of two models in Keras, but with a function in between them?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm using the Keras functional API and attempting to stack and train two models with a non-linear step in between them.

Say I want to train a chain of two models, Model A and Model B, where the output of Model A is used as the input of Model B, as one model, Model C. My understanding of how to do this is:

```
input_A = Input(input_shape_A)
output_A = ModelA(inputA)
output_B = ModelB(outputA)

model_C = Model(inputA, outputB)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50092589/how-to-vertically-stack-trained-models-in-keras)

The problem is that, in my case, I want to slice up the output of Model A before it goes into Model B, call another function on the slices which returns only one of them, and then use that slice as the input to Model B. So, Model B is only being trained on a fixed-size subset of Model A's output, which could be at arbitrary indices.

Something more like:

```
input_A = Input(input_shape_A)
output_A = ModelA(inputA)
input_B = custom_function(output_A)
output_B = ModelB(input_B)

model_C = Model(inputA, outputB)
```

I have not found any code examples so far that resemble this, and I am still trying to figure out if I can. The loss of Model B has to be integrated into Model A's training, but I need a function in between them. I was considering keeping them separate and trying to write out a custom loss function for Model A, but custom loss functions in Keras are seem to be very restrictive, and I haven't seen any examples for that approach so far, either.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you provide an `numpy` example of what your `custom_function` should do?

Comment: For example, it might split up the output of the first model and send a subset of it into the second, or do some other kinds of preprocessing before the results of the first model are passed into the second.